# Not able to connect USB printer after disconnecting and re-connecting in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-packages

We are getting permission popup for first time and able to print, but after disconnecting `USB` and re-connecting it again we are not able to print and not getting any permission popup message.

Answer (score 0):

[Disconnect and Connect Issue Fix](https://github.com/kechankrisna/flutter_usb_printer/pull/18)

Check the Pull Request you can able to solve it

The Main issue is mUsbDevice is not cleared when disconnecting so I have added that line in android of that package.
This issue is from the package site...
right now they approved my merge request so just download the package again it will fix your issue

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).